why is buildNumber property from buildnumber-maven-plugin not replaced by its value?
I am trying to use buildnumber-maven-plugin to generate a build number.
I can see that the build number is successfully created and logged with maven ant plugin.
Here's my plugin section :
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <!-- plugin used to extract the git hash and store it in ${buildNumber} -->
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>validate</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>create</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <doCheck>false</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
        <shortRevisionLength>7</shortRevisionLength>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>initialize</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <target>
              <echo>Build Number: ${buildNumber}</echo>
            </target>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

I can see the build number in the console :
[INFO] Executing tasks
[WARNING]      [echo] Build Number: 00d6f4d
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO]

However, when I use it in a variable like this :
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
  <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <format>'${version.tag}-${version.suffix}-'yyyyMMddHHmm'-${buildNumber}'</format>
    <archiveSite>true</archiveSite>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

${buildNumber} is actually the only variable that is not replaced by its value:
local-212-202404141336-${buildNumber}

